# Web requests becoming very slow when DNS server unreachable

Tags: c#, .net, performance, url-rewriting, dns

QA team discovered that when the webserver (serving embedded device UI) runs on a system where the primary DNS server is unreachable, the UI becomes unbearably unresponsive - taking some 16s for each action.

First I figured that serving static pages did not suffer from this problem.

Excluding my first suspect - logging - I have finally pinpointed the cause to Intelligencia.UrlRewriter (nuget package ver. 2.0.0.9). It appears that on each request, the rewriter makes a copy of all server variables, which includes "REMOTE_HOST". This is a dynamic variable and is only run when needed. This in turn involves a call to [HttpRequest.UserHostName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Question is simple: how to avoid reverse address lookups in web applications that use the UrlRewriter?

I offer a big hammer answer myself, but would like to hear other options.

Answer (score 0):

I have added another class library project with a simple http module:

```
public sealed class NoRemoteHostLookup : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += ContextOnBeginRequest;
    }

    private void ContextOnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current?.Request;

        if (request != null)
            request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] = request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
}
```

This is then referenced by the web app project and configured in web.config *before* the UrlRewriter:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add type="NoRemoteHostLookupModule.NoRemoteHostLookup, NoRemoteHostLookupModule" name="NoRemoteHostLookup" />
        <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

- Once the "REMOTE_HOST" variable is set, the framework refrains from resolving it later on when accessed by UrlRewriter.
- Well this is a theory. It works in my Visual Studio debugging session, but not on our mono target framework where I get a System.NotSupportedException.
- I made a bug report https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter/issues/9
- Meanwhile I transferred the rewrite rules to the nginx configuration and stripped away UrlRewriter in production.